# problem with strings add when i want to add persian(farsi) char

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

when i want to add persian(farsi) string to another string,the final string disordered like example:

```
function myFunction() {
debugger;
  var str1 = "1234#15701,";
   str1 += "(سلام),";
   str1 += '1570101/';
   str1 += "1234#15705,";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str1;
}
```

the final result is : "1234#15701,(سلام),1570101/1234#15705"
while it should be :
"1234#15701,[farsi string],1570101/1234#15705"

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try with below code, farsi string enclosed with in `span` with `dir='rtl'` attribute.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str1 = "1234#15701,";
   str1 += "(<span dir='rtl'>سلام</span>),";
   str1 += '1570101/';
   str1 += "1234#15705,";
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str1;
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```